# Mostrar una variable con espacios

Tags: javascript

```
var a = `
          \\  ^___^
           \\ (ooo)\\_______
             (___)\\       )\\/\\
                  ||----w |
                  ||     ||
`

          document.write(a);
```

Como hacen para mostrar esa variable como realmente es, y no linealmente?

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Intentaste con una etiqueta `<pre>`, al igual que se imprime en tu pregunta?

Comment: Respuesta: `document.write('<pre>' + a + '</pre>')`

Comment: @GustavoGarcía sigue viendose lineal

Comment: ¿Seguro? http://jsbin.com/wifegasazo/edit?js,output

Comment: Lo que pasará es que escapará algunos `\\`, pero sí se muestra conforme su estructura.

Comment: y como para que NO se escapen?

Comment: @Eduardo eso es una pregunta diferente. ¿Podrás editar tu pregunta para reflejarlo?

Comment: coloca tu comentario como respuesta

Comment: @Eduardo Estás preguntando 2 cosas diferentes: cómo hacer para que el ingreso se tome literal, y cómo hacer para imprimirlo. Eso no está aún en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

[**String.raw()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) es una función etiqueta de postprocesado para las plantillas de cadenas de texto, disponible en ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Se usa para obtener el string en crudo (*raw*) de la plantilla, sin interpretarlo. Es análogo a un string *verbatim* en JavaScript. Ver [compatibilidad](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals).

```
var literal = String.raw`Tex\to
No \\ "interpretado" \ .
Incluso \n no es un salto de línea`;
```

Además, cuando se imprime en el navegador, también lo estaría interpretando, por lo que se puede imprimir en una etiqueta `<pre>`.

```js
var a = String.raw`
          \\  ^___^
           \\ (ooo)\\_______
              (___)\\       )\\/\\
                   ||----w |
                   ||     ||
`;

document.write('<pre>' + a + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Para el que no entienda el uso de `String.raw`; es un **tagged template literal**. Esa característica vino en ES6 como lo indica Mariano y básicamente es una forma de construcción de texto. En este caso, `raw` [es una función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) el cual recibe tantos valores como sean pasados entre acentos graves por medio del signo de dolar y llaves, la cual retorna un texto plano construído a partir de dichos parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que concatenar las lineas con el **operador +** y dar los **espacios en blancos** que necesites, cuando declares la variable.

```
var a = 
        '\\  ^___^' +
        ' \\ (ooo)\\_______' +
        '   (___)\\       )\\/\\' +
        '        ||----w |' +
        '        ||     ||';
```

Comment: Hmm, no me funciona

Comment: En donde lo quieres imprimir?

Comment: document.write.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Usa la etiqueta pre. Mira mi comentario.